# How to define our own Twirl template format in Maven Java project without Play dependencies?

Tags: java, scala, maven, playframework, twirl

We're using Twirl template engine in Maven Java project without Play dependencies. We're using two Maven plugins to convert Twirl to Scala and then compile Scala files to be able to call render() method from Java.

At the moment, all our template files are TXT files, but we would like to define our own extension (.twirl or something)

Is it possible to achieve this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat

in Play-less project?

Comment: Could this be a possible solution? https://github.com/spray/twirl

Comment: It could be from wiring point of view, but it doesn't seem to support different extensions yet...